# Docker unable to process Dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I trying to create Dockerfile file from scratch on Windows7. However, currently have trouble on very first step. My Dockerfile is placed under `C:\Users\Arturas\Docker\Jenkins`. Virtual Box shared folder path on `c:\Users` and folder name on `c/Users` (defaults from boot2docker was not changed).

When I run (on git bash):

```
$ docker build --file Docker/Jenkins/ .
```

I get:

> unable to process Dockerfile: read C:\Users\Arturas\Docker\Jenkins:
>   The handle is invalid.

Dockerfile content is just one line:

> FROM jenkins

I just started learning Docker so my experience is very limited yet. However from tools like boot2docker I expect basic commands to work out of the box so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
cd /C/Users/Arturas/Docker/Jenkins
docker build -t myimage .
```

I assume here that you have a file named `Dockerfile` under the Jenkins folder.

The `-f` option of a [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) is for referencing the Dockerfile (if it is named differently for instance)

Don't forget to use the latest [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) (the [0.5.4 one](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases): an auto-extractible exe [`docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.4/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe)): it uses a VM named `boot2docker.iso` through VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the "Dockerfile" name

```
$ docker build --file Docker/Jenkins/Dockerfile .
```